# Python: Problem to add a column fron one dataframe to another dataframe in Panda

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 2 Dataframes of the same length and same structure and I need to add one column of one dataframe to the other.

The structure of the dataframes are the following:

DAT01

```
          Datestamp              Barra     USDMWH  MES  HORA ESTAC HSOL  
504128    2021010101  SAN_PABLO_____013  43.070000    1     1   VER  NSO   
504805    2021010102  SAN_PABLO_____013  37.970001    1     2   VER  NSO   
.
.
.
```

DAT02

```
          Datestamp              Barra     USDMWH  MES  HORA ESTAC HSOL  
504128    2021010101  SAN_PABLO_____110  42.060000    1     1   VER  NSO   
504805    2021010102  SAN_PABLO_____110  38.910000    1     2   VER  NSO   
.
.
.
```

I need add the column USMWH from DAT02 to DAT01 Dataframe with a different name.

The code that I have is:

```
DAT01[['CMGBA']]=DAT02[['USDMWH']]
```

The result that I obtain is:

```
          Datestamp              Barra     USDMWH  MES  HORA ESTAC HSOL  CMGBA
504128    2021010101  SAN_PABLO_____013  43.070000    1     1   VER  NSO   NaN
504805    2021010102  SAN_PABLO_____013  37.970001    1     2   VER  NSO   NaN
.
.
```

Also I tried using with the same result

```
DAT01['CMGBA']=DAT02['USDMWH']
```

What i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas function pandas.insert(column, name_column, values).
`DAT01.insert(le[enter image description here][1]n(DAT01.columns), "CMBGA", DAT02["USDMWH"])`

Comment: Thanks Misceria, but I obtain the same result

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

As DAT01 and DAT02 where a subset of a bigger Dataset, dataindexes in DAT02 and DAT01 where not the same.

Reseting the dataindex in both dataframes before do the operation solved the issue.

```
DAT01.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
DAT02.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
```

Regards to all!